# How to Select the value of the input box in Salesforce Lightning Web Component (LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have shared code in HTML. I want the feature in LWC. Please run the code and check.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the input field to select the contents of the text field.</p>
Name: <input type="text" id="myText" name="myText" value="Mickey" onclick="myFunction()">


<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myText").select();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can also check the above code from the link.
Click on the link and RUN
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGCN736KKCJJ

**My LWC Code**

```
    <lightning-input class="slds-inputNo-fld" value={ActualYield}
                                                        variant='label-hidden' data-policyid={PolicyId}
                                                        type="number" min="0" max="9999"
                                                        step="0.01" onclick={handleClickActualYield}></lightning-input>

handleClickActualYield(event){
        console.log(event.target) ;
        event.target.select();
        console.log(event.detail) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to SF Stack Exchange!

I have created a LWC out of the code you have shared. Please take a look at [this playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Ls1P44F4L/1/edit).

In case the playground disappears I am sharing the code here.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <p>Click the input field to select the contents of the text field.</p>
Name: <input type="text" id="myText" name="myText" value="Mickey" onclick={myFunction}>
```

JS:

```
myFunction(evt) {
    evt.target.select();
}
</template>
```

**EDIT** Updating my answer below since OP shared he is attempting to achieve the above using LWC's `lightning-input`.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification) for `lightning-input` the supported methods as of today are:

- blur
- checkValidity
- focus
- reportValidity
- setCustomValidity
- showHelpMessageIfInvalid

As you can see there's no `select` method. The `select()` is specific to `textarea` and `input` fields.

> The HTMLInputElement.select() method selects all the text in a
> textarea element or in an input element that includes a text
> field.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select).

When you trigger an `onclick` event for the `lightning-input` you are not triggering it on the input element you see on your screen because that `<input />` is wrapped in the `lightning-input`. In other words the `evt.target` is the `<lightning-input></lightning-input>` itself which does not support a `select()` method since it's a custom component. Additionally `console.log(evt.target.querySelector('input'));` returns `null` so there's no way to traverse down to the input child and trigger the select() method on it.

In order to achieve what you are asking for you will have to use a standard html `input` element.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it's now working.

It's showing that  **[e.target.select is not a function]**

Comment: @ArunangshuPal Are you saying that it is `now` working or that it is `not` working?

Comment: It's not working.

Showing an error that **[e.target.select is not a function]**

Comment: Can you post your code in your question so I can look at it?

Comment: I am using `lightning-input` instead of `input` tag

I have added my **LWC** code

Comment: @ArunangshuPal I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Is there any way to do this for `lightning-input`?

Comment: I'm sorry but that is not possible to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As per select() and setSelectionRange() both are not being supported via lighting-input. we can set select index as **selectionStart** and **selectionEnd** for solution.

```
JS:
myFunction(event) {
   event.target.selectionStart = 0 ;
   if(event.target.value){
      event.target.selectionEnd = event.target.value.toString().length ;
   }else{
      event.target.selectionEnd = 0 ;
   }
}
```